# The price of reading a variable

Tags: variables, memory, computer-science, cpu-architecture, declarative-programming

Suppose that we have variable (x) allocated in the memory and assigned a constant value (v). Are there cases where the operation of reading the content of the variable changes its value?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "a particular value" do you mean a constant, such as 5 ?

Comment: Yes, something like "int x=5;" in C.

Comment: Some cases, sure. Such as the whole situation with the indirect bit on PDP-10. And some loads that do a conversion in addition to loading. It's not common